# Variable in SQL -> ERROR PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Tags: sql, oracle

How can iterate a variable in select? I receive a error

```
    DECLARE
    ESTACION_ID NUMBER(6) :=3;
    BEGIN
          SELECT 
        100*TOTAL_TAX_AMB1/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITV2 WHERE ITV2.C_RESULTADO=1 AND ITV2.C_ESTACION_ID= ESTACION_ID ) AS TAXIS_Y_AMBULANCIAS_PRIMERA
                             ...
    END;
```

Comment: You should tell us the hole query and some sampledata so we can test the query and give you better answers... For a start you can use the `INTO` clause only on the top level `SELECT` they make no sense in subqueries...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a USING clause to bind a variable

```
DECLARE
    ESTACION_ID NUMBER(6) :=3;
    v_sql   varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
    v_sql   := 'SELECT 100*TOTAL_TAX_AMB1/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITV2 WHERE ITV2.C_RESULTADO=1 AND ITV2.C_ESTACION_ID= :1) AS TAXIS_Y_AMBULANCIAS_PRIMERA
             ...'
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO ... USING ESTACION_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Why ITV2.C_ESTACION_ID= :1

Comment: @Raulitus its a bind variable you can replace it with whatever you wnat. his answer should replace the error your having right ?

Comment: @Raulitus - you need to post **your whole query** - or at least a simplified version of it which still reproduces the problem - if you hope to get a helpful answer.

Comment: in [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables) article from Chris Saxon you can see how bind variables working.