# How can iterate a variable? I receive ERROR PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle

I want iterate a variable named C_ESTACION_ID but I received a ERROR PLS-00103

I tried the proposed solutions without success -> [Variable in SQL -> ERROR PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963940/variable-in-sql-error-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-select)

```
SELECT         
to_char (NVL(100*TOTAL_TAX_AMB1/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITV2_INSPECCIONES WHERE N_ANNO=2018 AND C_ESTACION_ID=28 AND N_FASE=1),0),'fm990.00') AS TAXIS_Y_AMBULANCIAS_PRIMERA
FROM(
     SELECT      
     SUM(CASE WHEN TIPO_USO_VEHICULO='Taxi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN TIPO_USO_VEHICULO='Ambulancia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS TOTAL_TAX_AMB1
     FROM(
          SELECT 
          INSP.C_ESTACION_ID AS ESTACION,
          -- -----------
          FROM 
          -- --------
          WHERE 
          INSP.N_ANNO=2016
          AND INSP.C_ESTACION_ID=28
          -- -----------
          GROUP BY 
          -- ------------
          ))
```

I want the variable C_ESTACION_ID to have the values 28 and execute the query, 29 and execute the query, 30 and execute the query...

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate" a variable?  Can you rephrase your question by showing sample table input and the expected output?

Comment: Please layout your code more clearly. **Readability is a feature**, especially when asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to help you improve your code.

Comment: Also don't post the same question more than once. You didn't get a satisfactory answer the previous time because you posted a snippet of code and failed to adequately explain your problem. For future reference you should have **edited that question** to provide more details and explanation, rather than asking a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the variable C_ESTACION_ID to have the values 28 and execute the query, 29 and execute the query, 30 and execute the query

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but I think you need to replace this line ...

```
INSP.C_ESTACION_ID=28
```

... with

```
INSP.C_ESTACION_ID in ( 28, 29, 30 )
```

However, that won't fix your `PLS-00103` error, which is caused by your peculiar nested select statements. You need to rewrite your query so it derives the totals in regular queries - or subqueries - and passes those values to an outer query to do the final arithmetic. Something like this:

```
 SELECT q1.N_ANNO
        , q1.C_ESTACION_ID as ESTACION
        , 100 * q1.TOTAL_TAX_AMB1 / q2.TAXIS_Y_AMBULANCIAS_PRIMERA ) TAXIS_Y_AMBULANCIAS_PRIMERA 
 FROM ( SELECT INSP.C_ESTACION_ID
               , INSP.N_ANNO
               , SUM(CASE WHEN TIPO_USO_VEHICULO='Taxi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                     + CASE WHEN TIPO_USO_VEHICULO='Ambulancia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS TOTAL_TAX_AMB1
        FROM  -- -----------
        WHERE INSP.N_ANNO = 2016
        AND INSP.C_ESTACION_ID in (28, 29, 30)
        GROUP BY INSP.C_ESTACION_ID
               , INSP.N_ANNO
      ) q1
      join (SELECT N_ANNO,  C_ESTACION_ID, COUNT(*) AS TAXIS_Y_AMBULANCIAS_PRIMERA
              FROM ITV2_INSPECCIONES 
              WHERE N_FASE=1) q2
       on q1.N_ANNO = q2.N_ANNO
       and q1.C_ESTACION_ID = q2.C_ESTACION_ID
```

Note: this may not provide the exact answer you need. Also it may be possible to simplify it further by combining the two subqueries `q1` and `q2` into a single subquery. But you have not posted a complete query nor posted a data model, sample data or explanation, so it is not possible for us to write an optimal working solution.

Comment: Thanks APC. That's what I want. I can't edit the question for having too much code. I'm newbie here and in the sql world sorry

Comment: I cleaned the code for try:                                                                                  
`SELECT q1.N_ANNO,q1.C_ESTACION_ID 
FROM( 
 SELECT INSP.C_ESTACION_ID , INSP.N_ANNO
        FROM  ITV2_INSPECCIONES INSP
        WHERE INSP.N_ANNO = 2016
        AND INSP.C_ESTACION_ID in (28, 32, 34)
        GROUP BY INSP.C_ESTACION_ID
               , INSP.N_ANNO) q1;
        JOIN (SELECT N_ANNO
              FROM ITV2_INSPECCIONES 
             ) q2
       on q1.N_ANNO = q2.N_ANNO
       and q1.C_ESTACION_ID = q2.C_ESTACION_ID`  but only show one row

Comment: That won't work because you don't select C_ESTACION_ID from ITV2_INSPECCIONES